# how to display custom message if data from pipe filter is empty in Angular8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-ui, angular-pipe

I have a component

```
<div *ngIf="(StatementData$ | async) as stmtData; else stillLoading">
  <div *ngFor="let p of plans">
    <h3>{{p.planShortName}}</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let s of stmtData.documents | PlanCodePipe : p.planCode">
      <span *ngIf="!s.isDownloading"><a (click)="fetchDocument(s);" class="click-link">{{s.label}}</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have a pipe filter PlanCodePipe

```
export class PlanCodePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], planCode: string): any {
    // console.log("in pipe for", sectionType);
    if (!items) return [];
    return items.filter(x => x.planCode === planCode);
  }
}
```

like u see in my component , sometimes this filter results in 0 matches.

```
<div *ngFor="let s of stmtData.documents | PlanCodePipe : p.planCode">
```

(it filters the documents based on the current plan code from the outer loop)
how to catch that and put "No Statements"? which is a tricky part because of the pipe filter i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not return the filtered items yet. Add a reference variable and check if the filtered items have a length. Create a flag from there if it is more than 0 then return the filtered item else maybe throw an error or a message. Here's my example based on your code.

```
export class PlanCodePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], planCode: string): any {
    // console.log("in pipe for", sectionType);
    const planCode = items.filter(x => x.planCode === planCode);
    const filteredValues = (planCode.length === 0) ? 'No values found' : planCode;
    return filteredValues;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul Thanks for the response. how would u check for no values found in the component html?

Comment: Hi @Margerine you can just pass an empty array in this line if that's the case.
const filteredValues = (planCode.length === 0) ? [] : planCode;
You will be able to know if there is no item selected if your html is blank. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late but it might helpful for someone else.

```
<p *ngIf="(stmtData.documents | PlanCodePipe : p.planCode)?.length <= 0">No record found!</p>
```